# Restrict v-text-field number input to single digit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use a series of v-text-field components to build an SMS verification code component, as such I need to restrict the input to just a single digit.

```
<v-text-field
            v-for="(num, key) of code"
            :key="key"
            type="number"
            outlined
            v-model.number="num.char"
        ></v-text-field>
```

I've found other answers which suggest using props such as `maxlength` or even `pattern` but these seem to be old answers for V1 of Vuetify... I'm using the latest release of V2

I could hook up a method to the `@input` event to manually check but feels like there is probably a simpler solution I'm missing

Answer (score 2):

Yo can define rules in data function:

```
data() {
  return {
    rules: {
      counter: value => value.length <= 1 || 'Max 1 character',
    }
  }
}
```

and then in template

```
<v-text-field
  v-for="(num, key) of code"
  :key="key"
  type="number"
  outlined
  v-model.number="num.char"
  :rules="[rules.counter]"
></v-text-field>
```

or you can still use `maxlength` property